# MongoDB: upsert when arrayFilters can't find a match

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like this:

`readers`

```
[{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "books": [
      {
        "type": "comic",
        "names": [
          "batman",
          "tintin"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "drama",
        "names": [
          "hamlet",
          "otelo"
        ]
      }
    ]
 },
 {...}]
```

Then I want to update my collection adding in array `names` matching by `type`.

When `type` exists works perfectly, in this example `romeo and juliet` is pushed correctly:

```
db.collection('readers').updateOne(
    { id: 123 },           
    {
      $push: {
        'books.$[element].names': 'romeo and juliet'
      }
    },
    {
      upsert: true,
      arrayFilters: [{ 'element.type': 'drama' }] // type exists
    }
  );
```

The problem come **when `type` is not matched:**

```
db.collection('readers').updateOne(
    { id: 123 },           
    {
      $push: {
        'books.$[element].names': 'hobbit'
      }
    },
    {
      upsert: true,
      arrayFilters: [{ 'element.type': 'fantasy' }] // new type
    }
  );
```

I expect this result but nothing is added:

```
{
   "id": 123,
   "name": "John Doe",
   "books": [
    {
      "type": "comic",
      "names": [
        "batman",
        "tintin"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "drama",
      "names": [
         "hamlet",
         "otelo"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "fantasy",
      "names": [
         "hobbit"             
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use an [Update with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html) to perform conditional array element update or insert. The update will happen as a single operation.

Comment: See this post [MongoDB 4.2 update pipeline: “Push or Update” in nested array](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-4-2-update-pipeline-push-or-update-in-nested-array/4300/2)

Answer (score 3):

As @GwenM said upsert works on document level, not on sub-documents. In your example upsert is appropriate if there are no documents with matching `id: 123`.

There is a problem with check-update pair of queries that it requires a transaction to ensure no race conditions.

I would recommend to use 3 atomic updates, wrapped into an [ordered bulk write](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/):

```
var b = db.readers.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

b.find({ id: 123 }).upsert()
 .updateOne({ $setOnInsert: { "name": "John Doe" } });

b.find({ id: 123, "books.type": { $nin: ["fantasy"] } })
 .updateOne({ $push: { "books": { "type": "fantasy" } } });

b.find({ id: 123, "books.type": "fantasy" })
 .updateOne({ $addToSet: { "books.$.names": "hobbit" } });

b.execute();
```

The first one is your upsert - it inserts a document with `id:123` if it doesn't exists.

The second query adds a `book` with `type: "fantasy"` if there is no such type yet.

The last query adds "hobbit" to book's `names` array - please note it's $addToSet not $push to ensure there are no duplicate names there.

You may want to skip the first query and forget about upsert at all if you don't want to insert new documents.

Answer (score 2):

You expect upsert to create the missing book but it's not how it works.

> Upsert: If set to true, creates a new document when no document
> matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not
> insert a new document when no match is found.

I think you have create 2 queries, one to check if the book exists and another one to update/create it (either push or you create the book)

Answer (score -1):

```
var id_value = 123
var type_value = 'drama'
var name_add = 'hobbit'
var output = db.readers.find(
    { $and : [
        { id: id_value },       
        {'books.type': type_value } 
    ]}
  );
if(output.count() == 0){
    //type doesn't exists

   db.readers.updateOne(
    { id: id_value },           
    {
      $addToSet: { books : { type : type_value, names : [name_add] }
      }
    },
    {
      upsert: false
    }
  );
}else{ 
// type exists
    db.readers.updateOne(
    { id: id_value },                  
    {
      $addToSet: {
        'books.$[element].names': name_add
      }
    },
    {
      upsert: true,
      arrayFilters: [{ 'element.type': type_value }] 
    }
  );
}
```

This could resolve the problem.